# Table transformation from variables

Tags: spss

My dataset looks like down below, but there are way more brands and categories.

[image]

I would like to transfer it the way that the brand is a row, and attribute (good quality, affordable) in the column

[image]

I've tried VARSTOCASES and i can calculate mean from it but thats not my desirable output

I need to posses brand names somehow - should withdraw it from all of my variables by

```
compute brand=char.substr(brand, 16)
```

like

```
compute brand=char.substr(P1_Good_Quality_BMW, 16)
```

I am fine with the varstocases part, then I can put my output like GQ to column, but dont know how to possess all of the names of brands and to let them match mean values of attributes

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: As far as I can tell, `varstocases` is exactly the way to do what you want. Please edit your question and add the syntax you used for `varstocases` and explain what was wrong with the results - this way we'll be able to see where the problem is and suggest corrections.

Comment: Hi, 
I can't reshape my data, so I got brands in rows and attribute in col. When I do varstocases from GoodQuality and make it as GQ, i got GQ and merged numbers from 3 brands. How to create custom table the way I want that? I don't get it, result of varstocases gives me values of all brands combined, but I dont have the brand variable itself to give it as row

Comment: see my attempt to answer - if this is not what you need please edit the original post and give a clearer description of what you tried and what you are trying to get.

Comment: stiil can't figure what the problem is - do you not have a list of brands/attributes and you would like to extract them from the variable list? also you lost me completely at "let them match mean values of attributes"... You still have to clarify better what the expected output is, and what's preventing you from getting it

Comment: The output is this 3x2 table in a big shortcut (if I figure out how to do that 3x2 ill do that on original dataset), where brands names are in rows and attributes are in columns and I want to calculate mean of each attribute for each brand. Varstocases let me merge all values of each attributes of all brands into one variable but I am still missing brands and SPSS must somehow understand which cell from varstocases belongs to which brand in order to do that

Comment: Hey. I dont know why my last answer is not here, so I'll repeat - Thank you, now I understand, the Index thing is next level function here and it allows to easy get every brand as a variable. You're truly amazing with your knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the data in the structure you intended - with a row for each brand and a column for each attribute:

```
varstocases /make GQ from P1_GoodQuality_BMW P1_GoodQuality_Audi P1_GoodQuality_Mercedes
        /make Afford from P2_Affordable_BMW  P2_Affordable_Audi  P2_Affordable_Mercedes
       /index=brand(GQ).
* at this point you should have the table you were trying to create, 
* we'll just extract the brand names properly.
compute brand=char.substr(brand, 16).
execute.
* now we have the data structured nicely, we can aggregate by brand.
dataset declare agg.
aggregate /out=agg /break=brand /GQ Afford = mean (GQ Afford).
dataset activate agg.
```